# Repositioning DXF Imported into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, autocad, dxf, tab

I have a polyline drawing from AutoCAD that I would like to reposition manually, if possible. During my efforts so far it has been turned into both a tab file and shapefile.

The main source of difficulty appears to arise from the fact that it was imported without a CRS and when I force one onto it it disappears.

Would anyone be able to render assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up QGIS what to do if no CRS definition found for a layer in Settings/Options/CRS CRS for new layers block.

If you know the CRS of the AutoCAD drawing and CRS is not asked during open, then

1. Load the DXF file into GIS
2. Open the layer properties dialog and select the correct CRS for the layer on the General tab
3. You may also change the CRS for the map canvas, lower right corner of the QGIS window
4. Use Save as from the popup menu of layer to save it into another
   format and CRS